# Jsoup runtime and debug behaviour is different?

Tags: java, jsoup

What code I use:

```
Connection conn = Jsoup.connect("https://e-disclosure.ru"); 
Document doc = conn.get(); 
String html = doc.html();
```

When I debug it in Eclipse, everything works fine, but when I run it outside ('java -jar...') I receive absolutely different data in the 'html' variable. Looks like some scripts were not executed (yes, maybe they should not, but in the debug mode it works!) or the server returned different data (but why? the address is the same, the headers are the same...). Can somebody explain it?

I expected the same behaviour for the code. I tried to check connection settings made by Jsoup by default, but it was the same (for example, user agent). The address is also unchanged.

Comment: I became closer to the issue resolution. My Eclipse runs on JDK 17 while my Mac OS uses JDK 20. If I run the application with JDK 17 all works fine. I still cannot find the reason of such behaviour. The testing will take much time (it might be some ban from the web site I connect to by the parameters special for SDK 20).

Comment: Try to set the user-agent string in your request - it looks like the different enviromnents that you use have different user-agent strings and hence the different behaviour that you get. To see which string you should use, try to access that site in your browser and check the response. If everything looks ok, use the same user-agent string as the browser does.